# Can jenkins hide its "execute shell" command when running a job?

Tags: jenkins

For Example if I put `bash abc.sh` in the "execute shell", The job output will be:

```
+ bash abc.sh
the output of the script
```

But what I want is only the output of this script, is there anything i can do to hide the `+ bash abc.sh`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems i find the answer....

```
set +x
<command>
set -x
```

This solves my problem.